# voiceover reading UITextFiled placeholder text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uiaccessibility

I have a UITextFiled with placeholder and when voiceover is on, it reads even placeholder text. How can i make it not to read the UITextField placeholder.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want that?

Comment: i have already added hint, so its reading double, once user starts editing it reads fine.

Comment: It's not your app's responsibility to work around this behavior. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you believe VoiceOver should behave differently.